# Set DLRadioButton marginWidth between icon and title

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, dlradiobutton

Before I upgraded to Swift 4.2 - Xcode 10.1 the `DLRadioButton` I used had an even spacing between the `icon` and the `title`. I never set the spacing and everything worked fine. After the upgrade the `icon` and the `title` overlaps

[image]

The [cocoapod for it](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/DLRadioButton/1.3.3/Classes/DLRadioButton.html) says that it uses a default `marginWidth` of `kdefaultmarginwidth`

[image]

I tried to set the `marginWidth` in code to anything that would definitely add spacing like `50.0` but the overlap stays. I read somewhere that the `kdefaultmarginwidth` spacing is `5.0`

**How can I fix the spacing?**

[image]

code:

```
let saleButton: DLRadioButton = {
    let button = DLRadioButton(type: .custom)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.setTitle("Sale", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.lightGray, for: .normal)
    button.marginWidth = 50.0 // I tried 5.0, 10.0, 20.0, even 100.0 but nothing
    return button
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubview(saleButton)
    // constraints get set
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to open an issue on the repo? :)

Comment: do you set any width constraints ?

Comment: @Sh_Khan yeah, on the button itself though. The button is pinned to the left of the view and on it's right is another DLRadioButton. Everything worked fine until the upgrade. I've never had a problem with the constraints before that

Comment: @AhmadF I just opened an issue on the repo, hopefully the response is quick. Thanks for the advice! : )

Comment: @Sh_Khan I just realized you asked about width constraints. The answer is no I don’t as far as saleButton.widthAnchor.constraintEqualTo(constant: xxx).isActive = true. I don’t use that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a choppy fix but it works for now because everything else I tried didn't work. Inside the `saleButton` closure, I had to add 4 empty spaces before I set the string for the title:

I changed this:

```
button.setTitle("Sale", for: .normal)
```

to this and the overlapping is now gone

```
// there are 4 empty spaces in front of the word Sale
button.setTitle("    Sale", for: .normal)
```

Here is the image below:

[image]